# How to release two android apps with same source code but different package names without refactor

Tags: android, release

I am looking for ways to release two android apps with same source code without any changes but with two different package name without refactoring.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Refactor code to change package name in a IDE (like a Idea or Eclipse)
2. Change package name in AndroidManifest.xml
3. Build an sign the application.

What exactly is causing a problem?

Comment: i have one project but how do i exactly create another with the same source code for a release without refactoring . help me pls and thanks for helping

Comment: Well, you have to change the application name AndroidManifest.xml at least.

Answer (score 0):

when ever you change package name to Refactor but in R file will not package name so and android market consider R file package name.

Change package name in AndroidManifest.xml file now R package name will automatic change. now change old src package name new one. make sure activity is proper mapping.

Comment: thanks for helping but help me with the procedure without refactoring

Answer (score -1):

What is bothering you? Just go ahead and release it with different package names. Make sure you make suitable refactoring in the code as well.

Comment: how do i give two different names and how to release the same as two different apps. help me thanks in advance